# Python sqlite3 placeholder for tuple of values of arbitrary length

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table with 6 columns and a tuple of length 6 which I want to insert. Code example looks like the following:

```
values = ('1', 'foo', 'bar', 'egg', 'spam', 'qwe')
cursor.execute(
    '''
    INSERT INTO customers VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ''',
    values
)
```

However I strongly dislike the idea to write `?` in a query body 6 times. I am looking for a way to do something like this:

```
values = ('1', 'foo', 'bar', 'egg', 'spam', 'qwe')
cursor.execute(
    '''
    INSERT INTO customers VALUES (?*)
    ''',
    values
)
```

Of course, to avoid writing `?` 6 times I can just use string formatting like this:

```
values = ('1', 'foo', 'bar', 'egg', 'spam', 'qwe')
cursor.execute(
    '''
    INSERT INTO customers VALUES {}
    '''.format(values)
)
```

But it is insecure. The best option I found is to calculate needed number of `?` (something similar proposed in answer to duplicate target):

```
values = ('1', 'foo', 'bar', 'egg', 'spam', 'qwe')
cursor.execute(
    '''
    INSERT INTO customers VALUES ({})
    '''.format(', '.join('?' for _ in values)),
    values
)
```

But I hope there can be more elegant way to achieve this, for example, something like `?*` I wrote above. Is there such a feature?

Comment: I don't think sqlite supports something like that.

Comment: @stovfl not a dupe. I have already tried that solution. I am looking for something more elegant.